# Sending payer name, email, etc to paypal create order API

Tags: paypal, e-commerce

Trying to send payer first name, last name and email to include it with payment information using the paypal create order api.  I found the documentation that stated there is a payer object, but has been deprecated. Trying to figure this out and needs to be captured whether the payer has a paypal account or not. I am using the advanced integration (hosted fields) SDK from paypal.

TIA....

Have tried several methods, including adding the contact info. to various json elements, but not able to produce what my client needs.

Answer (score 0):

The `payer` object [was deprecated](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create!path=payer&t=request). For PayPal payments, `payment_source.paypal` [should be used instead](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create!path=payment_source/paypal&t=request).

For advanced card payments, [`payment_source.card`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create!path=payment_source/paypal&t=request) exists but email is not a subfield. When using the current v2 version of advanced card-fields, the cardholder name is collected by those fields.

Edit: JS to make the cardholder name field required before submission

```js
 // Add click listener to submit button and call the submit function on the CardField component
  document
    .getElementById("multi-card-field-button")
    .addEventListener("click", () => {

     cardField.getState().then((data) => {
      if(data?.fields?.cardNameField?.isEmpty) {
        alert("Cardholder name cannot be empty");
      } else {
        cardField.submit().catch((error) => {
          resultMessage(
            `Sorry, your transaction could not be processed...<br><br>${error}`,
          );
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I have the cardholder name field as part of the form, but it is not required by default. However, I need to make it required.  I've been trying to look into the getState object to validate that field, but not sure how to implement it.  I have already put some form validation in place for some non-paypal fields also on the form, so not sure how this all fits together.

Comment: that is straightforward, see above